# return of a local variable by ref works

Tags: variables, reference, return, local

Take a look at this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class B{
public:
     int& f() { 
        int local_n = 447; 
        return local_n ; 
    }    // local_n gets out of scope here
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    int n = b.f(); // and now n = 447
}
```

I don't understand why n = 447 at the end of main, because I tried to return a reference to a local_n, when it should be NULL;

Answer (score 1):

Returning a reference to a local variable invokes undefined behavior - meaning you might get lucky and it might work... sometimes... or it might format your hard drive or summon nasal demons. In this case, the compiler generated code that managed to copy the old value off the stack before it got overwritten with something else. Oh, and references do not have a corresponding NULL value...

Edit - here's an example where returning a reference is a bad thing. In your example above, since you copy the value out of the reference immediately before calling anything else, it's quite possible (but far from guaranteed) that it might work most of the time. However, if you bind another reference to the returned reference, things won't look so good:

```
extern void call_some_other_functions();
extern void lucky();
extern void oops();

int& foo()
{ int bar = 0;
  return bar;
}

main()
{ int& x = foo();
  x = 5;
  call_some_other_functions();
  if (x == 5)
    lucky();
  else
    oops();
}
```

Comment: I was just trying to make myself an example why returning a local variable by reference isn't a good idea.
the returned value was only a copy of local_n? and how I can make a good example that work?

Comment: Well, if the fact that it's undefined behavior isn't enough of a not-good idea, then you'll probably need a somewhat more complex example to reinforce the idea...

Comment: I don't understand why in my example the value of local_n was copied out of reference, and in yours it didn't.
does it only because in your example there are another values in the stack?

Comment: Because you say `int n = b.f()`. The function is called, the reference is returned, and then, since `n` is not a reference, the value stored in the reference is copied out and placed in `n`. The difference in my example is that the returned reference is bound to another reference, not assigned to a non-reference.